# useState not working as expected - selectedElement in the state is resetting to initial value supplied in starting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have two events drag start and drag end. At the time of drag start I am deciding whether to move it or copy depending on some logic and `setSelectedElement` is running and setting the new element to it but as you can see console of new element in drag end and console for previously selected in drag start are both empty.

after some debugging, I found out it is turning to an empty string supplied in the very beginning of use state.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedElement, setSelectedElement] = useState("");
  const [diffX, setDiffX] = useState(0);
  const [diffY, setDiffY] = useState(0);
  const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("selected element changed");
      }, [selectedElement]);

    const handleDragStart = (event) => {
        console.log("drag start ");
    
        // console.log("class list", event.currentTarget.classList);
        console.log("previous selected element is ", selectedElement);
        let functionalityType = "";
        let elementSelected = "";
        let classList = event.currentTarget.classList;
        for (let i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
          //move element
          if (classList[i].includes("group")) {
            functionalityType = "move";
            break;
          }
        }
    
        if (functionalityType !== "move") {
          console.log("inside copy");
          elementSelected = event.currentTarget.cloneNode(true);
          elementSelected.style.position = "absolute";
          elementSelected.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
          elementSelected.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
        } else {
          console.log("inside move");
          elementSelected = event.currentTarget;
          // console.log("event current target", event.currentTarget);
        }
    
        setDiffX(event.clientX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        setDiffY(event.clientY - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        setSelectedElement(elementSelected);
      };
    
      const handleDragEnd = (event) => {
        console.log("drag end");
    
        let newElement = selectedElement;
    
        console.log("new element is", newElement);
    
        newElement.style.top = event.clientY - diffY + "px";
        newElement.style.left = event.clientX - diffX + "px";
    
        document.getElementById("MidArea").appendChild(newElement);
      }

    return (
    
        <div
                draggable={true}
                onDragStart={props.handleDragStart}
                onDragEnd={props.handleDragEnd}
                className="draggable"
              >);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the useState in your code?

Comment: @TusharShahi code edited to contain rest of the function still doesn't contain the whole function but necessary parts

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're doing `setSelectedElement(elementSelected);` outside else statement

Your code lacks some details to debug and find the missing piece however, drag and drop, I had this implemented sometime back, try the below

```
const stopDrag = () => {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
};

export const dragComponent = (dragRef) => {
    let coordinateOne = 0;
    let coordinateTwo = 0;
    let coordinateThree = 0;
    let coordinateFour = 0;

    const dragHandle = dragRef.current;

    const elementDrag = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        coordinateOne = coordinateThree - event.clientX;
        coordinateTwo = coordinateFour - event.clientY;
        coordinateThree = event.clientX;
        coordinateFour = event.clientY;
        dragHandle.style.top = `${dragHandle.offsetTop - coordinateTwo}px`;
        dragHandle.style.left = `${dragHandle.offsetLeft - coordinateOne}px`;
    };

    const dragDown = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        coordinateThree = event.clientX;
        coordinateFour = event.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    };

    dragHandle.onmousedown = dragDown;
};

function MyComponent(){

    const dragRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        dragComponent(dragRef);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div draggable ref={dragRef}>
            <h1> I am draggable..drag me around</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code but this is not what i am trying. My drag function is working fine but the problem is moving objects after copying them

Comment: moving objects after copying them? Is there any reason you're doing setSelectedElement(elementSelected); outside else statement?

Comment: there are multiple elements available in a say store first copy those element and bring them to the working space and then afterwards you are going to move them. In both cases i need to know the selected element

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
  setDiffX(event.clientX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        setDiffY(event.clientY - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        dragElementRef.current = elementSelected;
        setSelectedElement(elementSelected);
      
};
```

```
let dragElementRef = useRef(selectedElement);
....
....
     const handleDragEnd = (event) => {
//setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("drag end");
    
        let newElement = dragElementRef.current;
    
        console.log("new element is", newElement);
    
        newElement.style.top = event.clientY - diffY + "px";
        newElement.style.left = event.clientX - diffX + "px";
    
        document.getElementById("MidArea").appendChild(newElement);

//},500);

}
```

What I think is happening is your `handleDragEnd()` is being called before the next render cycle with updated value of state exists.
Try adding a setTimeout to add some delay.

Comment: did you get what he means by saying moving objects after copying them? it doesn't make sense :(

Comment: not immediately moving after copying. I am deciding whether elements need to be moved or copied.

This didn't work though and it doesn't target the core problem which is why the values are being reset

Comment: What could be the core issue according to you? Check console.log(typeof newElement) inside handleDragEnd, in both cases(the code i suggested and the code you have). Let me know.

Comment: during copy of element it works fine and it says type of newElement is "object" but when trying to move it. This doesn't work because new element is empty and type of newElement in this case is "string" in both cases with or without timeout

Comment: Ok. Can you try this edited answer with useRef?

Comment: same scenario value reset to empty string 
here is my code [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-paper-wzwk6?file=/src/App.js)
this is what i am trying to build [scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tutorial=getStarted)